# How to make recursive calling of subitems in vuejs2?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

In my laravel/blade app when I need to show comments of a product with parent_id I wrote a function with recursive calling of itself, like

```
public function showCommentItem( $commentsList, $parent_id, $product_id, $deeps, $backend_home_url, $images_dir, $current_template )
{
    $ret_html= '';
    $ret_html.= '<ul class="p-b-30">';
    foreach( $commentsList as $nextComment ) { // run list of comments
        if ( (int)$nextComment->parent_product_comment_id == (int)$parent_id ) {
            $approved_status_html= '';
            $ban_user_html= '';
            $rating_html= '';
            $status_html= '<span class="'.($nextComment->approved_status=='N'?'text-danger':'').'">'.$viewFuncs->getProductCommentApprovedStatusLabel( $nextComment->approved_status ).'</span>';
            $current_status_html= '.&nbsp;<span class="_tree_current_status ">Current Status</span>&nbsp;<b>'. $status_html . '</b>.&nbsp;';
            if ( $nextComment->approved_status == "N" or $nextComment->approved_status == "A" ) { // .text-center
               ...
            }

               ...
            
            $ret_html.= '<li class="'.($nextComment->subitems_count > 0 ? ' isFolder isExpanded ' : '').' p-b-10" >'.
                '<small>'./*$nextComment->user_id .'  '.$nextComment->user_active_status .'  : '.*/$nextComment->username.$ban_user_html.'</small>'./*'<br>' . */
                '<small>'.$current_status_html . $approved_status_html .
                '<span class="time pull-right">'.$nextComment->created_at.''.$rating_html.'</span>'.'</small>' . '<br>' ;
               ...
            if ( $nextComment->subitems_count > 0 ) {
                $deeps++;
                $ret_html.= $this->showCommentItem( $commentsList, $nextComment->id, $product_id, $deeps, $backend_home_url, $images_dir, $current_template);
            }
            $ret_html.= '</li>';
        } //                 if ( $nextComment->parent_product_comment_id == $parent_id ) {

    } //             recursiveforeach( $commentsList as $nextComment ) { // run list of comments
    $ret_html.= '</ul>';

    return $ret_html;
```

whrere $commentsList - my comments, $parent_id - is 0 at root calling, $product_id - common for all comments
and I got string for all comments with all functionality.

I try to make similar in bootstrap-vue project, like :

```
        <b-list-group>
              // I got root items only with getAdCommentsByParentId method 
            <b-list-group-item v-for="(nextAdComment) in getAdCommentsByParentId(0)" :key="nextAdComment.id" class="m-1 p-0">

                <div class="pre-formatted" v-html="nextAdComment.id+' ( '+nextAdComment.parent_ad_comment_id+') : '+concatStr(nextAdComment.text,50)"></div>
            </b-list-group-item>

        </b-list-group>
  ...
  
  
          methods: {
            getAdCommentsByParentId: function (parent_ad_comment_id) {

                var retArray= []
                if(!this.adComments) return []
                this.adComments.map((nextAdComment) => {
                    if (nextAdComment.parent_ad_comment_id == parent_ad_comment_id) {
                        retArray[retArray.length]= nextAdComment
                    }
                })
                return retArray
            },
```

But I do not know how to make recursive calling like I did with blade?

```
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.3.0",
"vue": "^2.6.11",
```

Thanks!

Comment: A quick and dirty solution I can provide you is to put your blade logic in a computed property and use the v-html property on a div. But there are definitely better ways of doing this.

Comment: I thought about such decision to make Method returning 1 string like I did in blade.
But I would prefer to use some *.vue file from my /components/ subdirectory, not working with 1 string...

Comment: I don't have lots of time to think about this right now, but I am assuming you would want to use a component that references itself, and uses a v-if to determine if it should render another level deeper of its self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found article

> Creating a Recursive Tree Component in Vue.js

from
https://alligator.io/vuejs/recursive-components/
Just what I need !